# Client JS: Return concatenation of async requests

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

*Disclaimer*. A friend of mine looking for a job of senior JS programmer sent the question to me. It's not a real problem then, but since I can imagine where and how it could become real, I've decided to post it here.

The question (a test task). It follows in my words, I can quote it here, if you think I got it wrong. *How to write a function which sends asynchronously requests to a given array of URLs, concatenates the result of each request and returns the concatenated string?* Oh, and there is another limitation: IE9+, current FF, current Chrome. The friend's answer (as polite as possible): no can do.

My answer was the same. Since there are no threads in browser JS (it's not NodeJS) and there is no `sleep` function, you cannot wait until all requests are processed. [Web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)? They [aren't supported in IE9](http://caniuse.com/#feat=webworkers). Also, they wouldn't help anyway. You can send the requests one-by-one, using `sync` flag of `XMLHttpRequest.open` but (here is my suggestion) if all requests are being sent to the same server which does some math that can be executed on a single CPU core only, your penalty is x4/x8/x16 times. Anyway, it's prohibited by the test task. Of course, you can concatenate the results in a callback function, but it's prohibited as well, since you must **return** the result.

But I'm not a JS guru, so I forwarded the question to my another friend who is (I think so). He suggested creating additional browser tabs, one per URL, which would send the request and write the result in its title. The main tab would loop thru the tabs, waiting until all the titles aren't empty. Since the tabs are executed independently, it should work. Then he tried the solution and said it works in IE only (with some side effects). In other words, no solution.

But the employer replied to my first friend with a statement the solution exists, though refused to send JS code of the function.

So, is the question a some kind of trolling? Or there is a solution I will be able to use if I ever face a situation when I really MUST concatenate async requests results (I know it's a bad idea in JS).

Comment: Barring some really ugly hack that should never be used in production code (like synchronous Ajax) and thus should not be the subject of an interview question, callbacks or promises are the solution for returning the result.  The current window cannot both process an async Ajax request AND wait for the async result to return it from the function.  So, I'd have to ask several questions back to see what was really being looked for in a response to that question. In the process I'd shown them I understand the tools and limitations available in Javascript and Ajax.

Comment: You can return a value that will know the result, but not the result directly. Closest thing I could think of are a mix of generators and promises but I can't really say if that'd be `returning` the result.

Comment: I would communicate through `localStorage`... But still, you can only execute parallel code in IE9 if you create a new tab, but that will not work on chrome and ff. For ch and ff you have workers.

Comment: Don't take the task too literally. If you should *return the result* from an *asynchronous* task, that means you should use a callback or return a promise for the value, as you cannot `return` it indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a discussion of various options:

1. Use **synchronous Ajax** and return the result.  Synchronous ajax is a horrible idea and the challenge said to use async requests so presumably this is a no-go, but I include it here because it does let you directly return the result.
2. If you use async ajax in the same window, then you simply cannot return the result directly.  You can **call a callback** when the result is done or you can **return a promise** which will then call a `.then()` handler callback when the result is available.  You cannot spin and wait for the async ajax to finish because the Ajax complication can't get back to you until you return and let the event queue get to the next events.
3. If you **put Ajax into a webWorker** (either synchronous or asynchronous), you can code the webWorker however you want, but the only way it can communicate back to the main thread is via a message and that message can't be received by the main thread until you return back from your original function to get to the next messages in the event queue.  Again, you can't spin and wait for the message from the webWorker because it won't get back to you until AFTER the current thread of execution finishes.  So, you have to return from your function BEFORE you can get the result from the webWorker.
4. You can **put the Ajax into an iFrame or another window** and then communicate back to the current window from the other window when it is done.  This has all the same issues as the previous solutions in that you won't be able to receive communication back from the iFrame or other window until after the current function has finished and returned so that events can get processed off the event queue.  So, you have to return from your function BEFORE you can get the result from another window.
5. You can **put the Ajax into an iFrame or another window and then poll some variable in that window from your main window**.  There is a possibility that this might work in some browsers, but I was unable to build a successful test to prove it could work.

Comment: Those new gravatars are confusing, aren't they?

Answer (score 0):

1st thought:

```
function concatenatesResults(urls, cb) {
    var temp = [], i = urls.length
    urls.forEach(function (url, key) {
        //its async so not block the foreach
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            success: function (data) {
                temp[key] = data //be sure it is in a good order
                i--
                if (i === 0) cb(temp.join("")) //if this is teh last one return the data
            }
        })
    })
}
concatenatesResults([/* URLS*/], function(data){console.log(data)})
```